# fscanf returning nonsense values

Tags: c++, .obj

I'm trying to read from a file following this tutorial:
http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-7-model-loading/

The problem is that when I try to copy the code and do fscanf, the values are always initialized to crazy values like -848228281 or something similar.
The first time I read the values for the vertices it works, but not for the faces.

```
while (!(feof(fp)))
{
    read = fscanf(fp, "%c", &ch);       
    if (/*read == 4 && */ch == 'v')
    {
        // this works
        read = fscanf(fp, "%f %f %f\n", &x, &y, &z);
        vertices.push_back(vector3(x, y, z));
        //glVertex3f(x, y, z);
    }
    else if (ch == 'f')
    {
        GLint vertexIndex[3], uvIndex[3], normalIndex[3];

        // this line below does not work
        int matches = fscanf(fp, "%d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d\n",
            &vertexIndex[0], &uvIndex[0], &normalIndex[0],
            &vertexIndex[1], &uvIndex[1], &normalIndex[1],
            &vertexIndex[2], &uvIndex[2], &normalIndex[2]);
        if (matches != 9)
        {
            printf("Incompatible file!");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

My obj file is the same as in the tutorial.

Comment: It's hard telling what could be wrong without a [mcve].

Comment: From the example it looks like an out-of-scope error. How do you get the values from `vertexIndex` `uvIndex` and `normalIndex` outside of the `else if` block? Since after this they will be invalid.

Comment: @Yastanub I put a breakpoint at if (matches != 9) and inspect the values in the watch window there.

Comment: And are you sure you put the breakpoint in the correct line? What about `matches` what does it contain? And have you only encountert Problems in the watch window or are the values wrong past that point?

Comment: They are wrong past that point. I put a cout after the if statement as well. matches returns 0.

Comment: If `matches` returns zero then that means `fscanf` didn’t find the information you wanted it to find and the values are undefined, as you’ve noticed.

Comment: Unrelated: [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Answer (score 0):

The code will enter the `else if (ch == 'f') { ... }` clause when it encounters the line of data that reads:

```
s off
```

because of the `'f'` characters.  But the subsequent attempt to read the numeric values will fail (for obvious reasons).